# How can I display a 'random' feed item using this jQuery zRSS plugin code?

Tags: jquery, rss, random, feed

I am running and using the **zRSSFeed jQuery plugin** (http://www.zazar.net/developers/zrssfeed/) to pull feed items from my WordPress blog and display a single feed item within a seperate XHTML file (outside of the WordPres blog). It works perfectly displaying the latest item in the feed specified.

**I would like it to display a RANDOM item** from the feed through, rather than just the latest or newest item.

Could the code be amended to do this, and if so how?

```
/**
 * Plugin: jquery.zRSSFeed
 * 
 * Version: 1.0.1
 * (c) Copyright 2010, Zazar Ltd
 * 
 * Description: jQuery plugin for display of RSS feeds via Google Feed API
 *              (Based on original plugin jGFeed by jQuery HowTo)
 * 
 *
 **/

(function($){

var current = null; 

$.fn.rssfeed = function(url, options) { 

    // Set pluign defaults
    var defaults = {
        limit: 10,
        header: false,
        titletag: 'h6',
        date: false,
        content: true,
        snippet: false,
        showerror: true,
        errormsg: 'View our customer testimonials <a href="http://renownestates.com/blog/category/testimonials/">here</a>',
        key: null
    };  
    var options = $.extend(defaults, options); 

    // Functions
    return this.each(function(i, e) {
        var $e = $(e);

        // Add feed class to user div
        if (!$e.hasClass('rssFeed')) $e.addClass('rssFeed');

        // Check for valid url
        if(url == null) return false;

        // Create Google Feed API address
        var api = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/feed/load?v=1.0&callback=?&q=" + url;
        if (options.limit != null) api += "&num=" + options.limit;
        if (options.key != null) api += "&key=" + options.key;

        // Send request
        $.getJSON(api, function(data){

            // Check for error
            if (data.responseStatus == 200) {

                // Process the feeds
                _callback(e, data.responseData.feed, options);
            } else {

                // Handle error if required
                if (options.showerror)
                    if (options.errormsg != '') {
                        var msg = options.errormsg;
                    } else {
                        var msg = data.responseDetails;
                    };
                    $(e).html('<div class="rssError"><p>'+ msg +'</p></div>');
            };
        });             
    });
};

// Callback function to create HTML result
var _callback = function(e, feeds, options) {
    if (!feeds) {
        return false;
    }
    var html = '';  
    var row = 'odd';    

    // Add header if required
    if (options.header)
        html += '<div class="rssHeader">' +
            '<a href="'+feeds.link+'" title="'+ feeds.description +'">'+ feeds.title +'</a>' +
            '</div>';

    // Add body
    html += '<div class="rssBody">' +
        '<ul>';

    // Add feeds
    for (var i=0; i<feeds.entries.length; i++) {

        // Get individual feed
        var entry = feeds.entries[i];

        // Format published date
        var entryDate = new Date(entry.publishedDate);
        var pubDate = entryDate.toLocaleDateString() + ' ' + entryDate.toLocaleTimeString();

        // Add feed row
        html += '<li class="rssRow '+row+'">' + 
            '<'+ options.titletag +'><a href="'+ entry.link +'" title="View this feed at '+ feeds.title +'">'+ entry.title +'</a></'+ options.titletag +'>'
        if (options.date) html += '<div>'+ pubDate +'</div>'
        if (options.content) {

            // Use feed snippet if available and optioned
            if (options.snippet && entry.contentSnippet != '') {
                var content = entry.contentSnippet;
            } else {
                var content = entry.content;
            }

            html += '<p>'+ content +'</p>'
        }

        html += '</li>';

        // Alternate row classes
        if (row == 'odd') {
            row = 'even';
        } else {
            row = 'odd';
        }           
    }

    html += '</ul>' +
        '</div>'

    $(e).html(html);
};
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

basically, take out the loop and use Math.random() to select an entry

http://jsfiddle.net/Vdyb5/

Comment: thanks for your reply Dave! I've amended the jquery to what you posted above, but now nothing displays. Would you be able to post the entire script with your changes implemented please? Just to make sure ive not got anything wrong or missed anything out.

Comment: ok me a while to figure it out as I kept changin the 'limit' back to "1" thinking i only wanted one to display, but then realised this was the 'pool' out of which one would be selected. :) Thank you again!!